# How to insert variable in a switch statement return with Xtend?

Tags: switch-statement, xtend

With this **Xtend** code :

```
«switch l.name {
case 'java': 'mvn compile..../«d.name»/src/.........'
default: 'bash..../«d.name»/src/......'
}»
and d.name = "Joe"
```

I **want** to return this formated String with the inserted variable :

```
mvn compile..../Joe/src/.........
bash..../Joe/src/.....
```

and **not** :

```
mvn compile..../«d.name»/src/.........
bash..../«d.name»/src/......
PS : case 'java': 'mvn compile..../'«d.name»'/src/.........'
doesn't work
```

I can't / I don't know how to insert anything into the returned String.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution :**

```
«switch l.name {
case 'java': 'mvn compile..../'+d.name+'/src/.........'
default: 'bash..../'+d.name+'/src/......'
}»
and d.name = Joe
```

will return as expected :

```
mvn compile..../Joe/src/.........
bash..../Joe/src/.....
```

So add **`+`** to concatenate the different parts of the returned String and as we are inside of `«...»` don't add `«»`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `'''template string with  «placeholderExpression» parts'''` at any place where a Xtend expression can be used - i.e. even inside `«placeholderExpression»`. So this should work:

```
«switch l.name {
case 'java': '''mvn compile..../«d.name»/src/.........'''
default: '''bash..../«d.name»/src/......'''
}»
and d.name = "Joe"
```

However: Don't nest this too deep or your head will explode ;-)

Comment: Indeed it works fine too! Both methods seem identical to use from a syntax and logical point of view.